# Will take less time if i execute command in single line databricks notebook?

Tags: scala, azure, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I want to understand time constraint if i execute any command in single line vs multiple lines in databricks notebook.

Suppose i am running any command(line of codes) in multiple line(cells) and same command i am execute in single line, will it take less time?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more specific. What commands, exactly? As written, there's no clear answer to be had, as it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, what issue you're running into, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is impacting the execution time duration.
Simply I am printing the "Hello World" String in two different cells and calculating the execution time using the below code.

```
val t1 = System.nanoTime
val duration = (System.nanoTime - t1) / 1e9d
```

Attaching the screenshot for more details.

**1)** Executing the two print statement in one cell.
[image: One cell screenshot]

**2)** Executing the two print statement in two separate cells.
[image: Two cell screenshot]

Hope that helps.